# SharedModule Service constructor is called multiple times

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular `Core/Feature/Shared` modules pattern.

When `CoreComponent` (the app's home page) is rendered, the `DataStorageService`'s constructor (which is used in `CoreComponent`'s constructor) is called multiple times (which results in a AJAX call each time  the constructor is called)

Please don't mark my question as duplicate, as my question is a bit different than similar questions which have been asked and answered here before.
I attached my code to show what I mean ( I have shortened it for simplicity).

**core/shared.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  exports: [... ],
})
export class SharedModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [XHRService, DataStorageService]
    };
  }
}
```

**shared/services/data-storage.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataStorageService {
  constructor(private xhr: XHRService) {
    this.loadEvents()
  }

  public loadOrigination = () => this.xhr.getOriginationsList().subscribe(this.originationsSource);
  public loadEvents = () => this.xhr.getEventsList().subscribe(this.eventsSource);

  private eventsSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  private originationsSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  public originations$ = this.originationsSource.asObservable();
  public events$ = this.eventsSource.asObservable();
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
   ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**core/core.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations:
    [
      CoreComponent,
      ...
    ],
  exports: [
    CoreComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CoreRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
    ...
  ],
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

**core/core.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements{

  constructor(public dataStorageService : DataStorageService) { }

}
```

Comment: Making calls from inside of constructors is a bad idea in any context. Can you move the code out?

Comment: Where  should I move them to?

Comment: Put it somewhere where it makes sense, not in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is as expected, The Constructor is a default method of the class that is executed when the class is instantiated and ensures all the fields of the class are properly initialized. The constructor of the component is called when Angular constructs components tree. All lifecycle hooks are called as part of running change detection. So whenever you are injecting core components to any module it is going to get called.

The suggestion to fix this issue would be, remove your **`loadEvents()`** outside the constructor/ call it in the component with ngOnInit life cycle hook.

```
 ngOnInit(){
   this.dataStorageService.loadEvents();
 }
```

Comment: Any idea for anywhere else I can place it ?

Comment: what do you mean by anywehere

Comment: I mean I don't want to call l within a component, my question if you can think of anywhere else I can move it to, Thank you!

Comment: Can't a service initiate a function call??

Comment: component is the one that needs to make the call when needed, sorry i am not sure about the requirement

Comment: I want all the source to be loaded once. (what wouldn't be the case if I call it every time the user is navigates back to the component) that's why I don't want to call it from the component. I know there's work around for it to check if the data exists but it would've been much easier and tidier if it had been possible get it done in different way.

Comment: I think what you said is not precise , when the service is not shared between two module is only fired once, go ahead as check!